# 5 local notifications every day

Tags: ios, localnotification

I want to have 5 local notifications every day and here is the code I used to trigger local notification, everything is cool, but if the first notification comes out, and if I run the APP foreground， than or the other notification will not come out. Please help to keep all the notifications even if I run the APP foreground.

```
UILocalNotification* n1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *c1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // gets default calendar

    NSDateComponents *co1 = [c1 components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // gets the year, month, day,hour and minutesfor today's date

    [co1 setHour:15];

    [co1 setMinute:54];

    n1.fireDate = [c1 dateFromComponents:co1];

    n1.alertBody = @"3:54";

    n1.soundName = @"alarm.wav";

    n1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    n1.alertAction= @"3:54";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n1];

    UILocalNotification* n2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *c2 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // gets default calendar

    NSDateComponents *co2 = [c2 components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // gets the year, month, day,hour and minutesfor today's date

    [co2 setHour:15];

    [co2 setMinute:55];

    n2.fireDate = [c2 dateFromComponents:co2];

    n2.alertBody = @"3:55";

    n2.soundName = @"alarm.wav";

    n2.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    n2.alertAction= @"3:55";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n2];

    UILocalNotification* n3 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *c3 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // gets default calendar

    NSDateComponents *co3 = [c3 components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // gets the year, month, day,hour and minutesfor today's date


    [co3 setHour:15];

    [co3 setMinute:56];

    n3.fireDate = [c3 dateFromComponents:co3];

    n3.alertBody = @"3:56";

    n3.soundName = @"alarm.wav";

    n3.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    n3.alertAction = @"3:56";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n3];

    UILocalNotification* n4 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *c4 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // gets default calendar

    NSDateComponents *co4 = [c4 components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // gets the year, month, day,hour and minutesfor today's date

    [co4 setHour:15];

    [co4 setMinute:57];

    n4.fireDate = [c4 dateFromComponents:co4];

    n4.alertBody = @"3:57";

    n4.soundName = @"alarm.wav";

    n4.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    n4.alertAction = @"3:57";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n4];

    UILocalNotification* n5 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *c5 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // gets default calendar

    NSDateComponents *co5 = [c5 components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // gets the year, month, day,hour and minutesfor today's date

    [co5 setHour:15];

    [co5 setMinute:58];

    n5.fireDate = [c5 dateFromComponents:co5];

    n5.alertBody = @"3:58";

    n5.soundName = @"alarm.wav";

    n5.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    n5.alertAction = @"3:58";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n5];
```

Answer (score 2):

If your App is in `foreground` No notification is presented but this below method will be called,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
}
```

First you should identify the notification by `userinfo` attached in it.(if you haven't given, give `userinfo` to every notification.)

present any alert when you get a call in this method.